# Not able to pass a object to my custom compound control

Tags: android, android-custom-view, mvp

I am using MVP for my Android project.
I have an POJO `Product` and need to be able to show the details of this product in a separate activity. This can activity needs 2 different layout:
1. a layout with a button to print the details of this product
2. a layout with 2 buttons to add the selected product to a wishlist or cancel the action

Both above described layouts have the same xml layout to display the details so I want to make a compound component, like desbribed [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components#compound)

I want to implement this with the MVP architecture. So my goals is that I have a class which extends `ConstraintLayout` and serves as my view. The view has it own presenter to set the `TextView` s with the data from the `Product`.

All of this works, but I am not able to pass the selected `Product` from the presenter of the activity that has the compound component, which results that the data of the product is not shown in the compound.

the `DetailCompound.java`

```
public class DetailsCompound extends ConstraintLayout {
    TextView productTv, brandTv, sizeTv, extraTv, materialTv, familyTv;
    ImageView codeImg;
    DetailPresenter presenter;

    public DetailsCompound(Context context, Product product) {
        super(context);
        this.initViews(context);
        this.createPresenter(product);
    }

    private void initViews(Context context) {
        inflate(this.getContext(), R.layout.product_details, this);

        //initialize views
    }

    private void createPresenter(Product product) {
        this.presenter = new DetailPresenter(this, product);
    }
}
```

the `DetailPresenter.java`

```
public class DetailPresenter implements OnLoadListener {
    DetailsCompound compound;
    StorageManager storage;
    Product product;

    public DetailPresenter(DetailsCompound compound, Product product) {
        this.compound = compound;
        this.storage = new StorageManager();
        this.storage.setOnLoadListener(this);
        this.setProduct(product);
    }

    private void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;

        //set details of product in view

        this.storage.getProductCodeImage(this.product.getCodeUrl());
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoad(Object loadedObj) {
        this.compound.codeImg.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) loadedObj);
    }
}
```

the `activity_product_detail.xml` which includes the compound

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingHorizontal="8dp"
    tools:context=".productdetail.ProductDetailActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/product_details"
        layout="@layout/product_details"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="534dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/print_btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/print_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Print"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

the `ProductDetailActivity.java`

```
public class ProductDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button printBtn;

    DetailsCompound productDetails;
    ProductDetailPresenter presenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_detail);

        createPresenter();
        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews() {
        this.productDetails = new DetailsCompound(this.getApplicationContext(), this.presenter.product);
        printBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.print_btn);
    }

    private void createPresenter() {
        this.presenter = new ProductDetailPresenter(this);
    }
}
```

I don't have a clue how to "link" the `<include>` in the `activity_product_detail.xml` with the `DetailCompound.java`

Comment: The flow of the presenter and the compound is well made, the thing I'm seeing as maybe the problem is the context of the compound, since is not extending an AppCompatActivity, If you need to reuse views, you can have 1 activity with multiple fragments, and that will be for sure , I think, cleaner for you to understand

Comment: I've read about Fragments but never used them, is this case made to be solved with fragments?

Comment: yes, it will be easier for you to understand and work with

Comment: I figured it out with compound components, I'll post an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I figured it out...

My logic was great, but I just didn't know how to use a compound component.
Here's how I fixed it:

the `activity_product_detail.xml` which implements the compound:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingHorizontal="8dp">

    <com.example.imanager.compounds.details.DetailsCompound
        android:id="@+id/product_details"
        android:layout_width="395dp"
        android:layout_height="534dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/print_btn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/print_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Print"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It didn't work because I used an `<include>` tag instead of implementing the compound 
java class itself. In this java class the inflater is used to inflate the reusable UI component:

```
private void initViews() {
        LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.compound_product_details, this);

        //init views
    }
```

In the activity, `ProductDetailActivity.java`, that holds the compound we just instantiate the compound doing this:

```
this.productDetails = (DetailsCompound)findViewById(R.id.product_details);
        this.productDetails.getPresenter().setProduct(this.presenter.product);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can send any details from your POJO to another activity through Intent

Comment: yes, but that is not what I meant. I want to send a POJO from an activity to the compound component that holds it. I made the `activity_product_detail.xml` that includes another xml file.
So I need to send the POJO from the activity holding the compound to the compound itself.